# how to call action in controller in asp.net mvc with jqGrid Custom Search

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

All. 
I use jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC. i create a js file for jqGrid table and this file have `getdata(getlist)` and CRUD. this is not problem for me. 
my problem is not call action in controller with button. this not work for me.
my example is :

```js
$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "/JqGrid/GetList",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Get',
        colNames: ['ProductID', 'ProductName', 'UnitPrice'],
        colModel: [
            { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'ProductID', index: 'ProductID', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'ProductName', index: 'ProductName', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'UnitPrice', index: 'UnitPrice', editable: true }
        ],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        height: '100%',
        viewrecords: true,
        loadonce: true,
        caption: 'Jqgrid List A.saadati',
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            ProductID: "0"
        },
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: false
    }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: true },
        {
            // edit options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: '/JqGrid/Edit',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        },
        {
            // add options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: "/JqGrid/Create",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterAdd: true,
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        },
        {
            // delete options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: "/JqGrid/Delete",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterDelete: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            msg: "Are you sure you want to delete this task?",
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        });


    $('#filterButton').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        filterGrid();
    });
});

function filterGrid() {
    var postDataValues = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');

    // grab all the filter ids and values and add to the post object
    $('.filterItem').each(function (index, item) {
        postDataValues[$(item).attr('id')] = $(item).val();
    });

    $('#grid').jqGrid().setGridParam({ postData: postDataValues, page: 1 }).trigger('reloadGrid');
    alert("Fucntion is call with button,it is ok");
}
```

Note: `$('#filterButton').click( ....` is call `filterGrid` but `filterGrid` not work. i have a text box and button for search.

and my action is

```cs
public JsonResult GetList(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, string ProductName)
{
    int PageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    int PageSize = rows;
    var ListResult = db.Products.ToList();
    int TotalRecords = ListResult.Count;
    var TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)TotalRecords / (float)rows);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductName))
    {
        ListResult = ListResult.Where(p => p.ProductName.Contains(ProductName)).ToList();
    }
    if (sord.ToUpper() == "DESC")
    {
        ListResult = ListResult.OrderByDescending(s => s.ProductName).ToList();
        ListResult = ListResult.Skip(PageIndex * PageIndex).Take(PageSize).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        ListResult = ListResult.OrderBy(s => s.ProductName).ToList();
        ListResult = ListResult.Skip(PageIndex * PageIndex).Take(PageSize).ToList();
    }
    var jsonData = new { total = TotalPages, page, records = TotalRecords, rows = ListResult };
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Of course i know `filterGrid` Function is for jqGrid and not call top action. but this code not work for me and i try to another way to call action with URL but it not work too.

please a way for help me. thank you.

Comment: jqGrid supports **two** alternative scenarios: *server side* sorting, paging and filtering and *client side* sorting, paging and filtering. You use currently server side sorting and paging, but *no filtering* in your server code and use `loadonce: true`, which force client side sorting, paging and filtering. You should decide which scenario (client side or server side) you need. If the number of totally rows (`db.Products.Count`) is not large (less as 1000 or less as 10000) then *client side* (`loadonce: true`) scenario is recommended.

Comment: Moreover you wrote "$('#filterButton').click( .... is call filterGrid but filterGrid not work." You should include the code fragment where you register `$('#filterButton').click()` exactly if it's your main problem. If you would use it on the wrong place then it will not work independent from any jqGrid problems. You can include `alert("in click");` as the first line of `$('#filterButton').click(function () {/*Here*/})` code to test it. You should describe the problem "not work" more exact. Do you see the searching toolbar? ... It's important which version of jqGrid and from which fork you use

Comment: thank you fore answer for me. not toolbar for me in jqgrid. i have a 3 cluomns and a nav gird in down grid and add ,edit,delete,refresh,and search correct working. i want filter with server side.

Comment: my code is if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductName))
    {
        ListResult = ListResult.Where(p => p.ProductName.Contains(ProductName)).ToList(); }
   i  want use  contains with a text box  and button .  Oleg I call function  and that give me alert ok (alert("Fucntion is call with button,it is ok");) . one question? my function is client side? or server side call? please change me code . i very try to  work this. but it not work .

Comment: There are **many ways** to implement your requirements. For example, you can just call `filterFoolbar` method. It creates additional toolbar between column header and the data of the grid. If the user type a text over `ProductName` column then the parameter will be send to `GetList` **automatically**. You can add `search: false` property in `UnitPrice` column if you don't want to search for the values in the column.

Comment: ok. this way : i do loadonce to false. and change my function  to this function filterGrid() {
   
    var ProductName = $(".filterItem").val();
    $('#grid').jqGrid().setGridParam({ ProductName: "vh", page: 2 }).trigger('reloadGrid');
    alert("Fucntion is call with button,it is ok");
} i can call action. for example i send vh to action for ProductName prameters. it is string. but ProductName in action is null. why?

Comment: Thank You Oleg . i understand client and server side search in jqgrid.  i send a value to action and get value and etc.... but one problem for me. i change paraeters name to     public JsonResult GetList(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, string filterItem) -->  filterItem i get value . i want change parameter name to product name ... but i get null value... thnak you oleg.